# Seek vs Truncate to grow (prealocate) file size

Tags: go, file-io

I want to preallocate space for file(s).
how do you grow file(s) size?

```golang
(*os.File).Seek(size,os.SEEK_SET)
or
(*os.File).Truncate(size)
```

what is the difference between the two?

Comment: A Truncate() call also typically does not allocate space either. Whether seek-and-write creates a hole is OS/file-system-dependent, but if it does, truncate will usually do so as well.

Comment: thanks @torek
i was also wondering, if i write zero bytes at the end of the file after truncate or seek, will that help?
-
i've read some, and it seems the behaviour could vary between different OS or filesystems

Comment: Linux and other Unix-like systems will return zero if you call write() with a zero byte count. If you meant: write one byte whose *value* is zero, that may or may not cause block allocation, and if it does cause block allocation, it may allocate just a single block, or—depending on OS and file system—might fill in the entire hole. Your best bet if you want  to avoid holes is to write random data, which cannot be compressed or elided; or, you can write blocks-of-all-zero-bytes and hope (or check) whether the file system does compression and/or detects all-zero-bytes and turns them into holes.

Comment: For instance, if you are using ZFS and have compression and block de-duplication turned on, writing a fixed pattern of nonzero data could (a) compress the data and/or (b) de-duplicate the data. Random data with high entropy would fail to compress and de-duplicate, so that would force real block allocation. This is, of course, quite *slow* so a smarter/faster approach is to work *with* the file system: ZFS probably has a way to pre-allocate space to files. The obvious drawback is: now your operation is tied to ZFS. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Seek](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Seek) function can change the current position in the open file. [Under the hood](https://github.com/golang/go/tree/2b50ab2aee75d3c361fcd1eb39e830e2e73056b6/src/internal/poll/fd_unix.go#L422), this function simply calls the [lseek](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html) system call. This allows the file offset to be set beyond the end of the file, without ever changing the file size. If you try to set an offset larger than the file size, you will get the [sparse file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file) - a file with holes (contiguous ranges of bytes having the value of zero) on the offset space. Sparse files make efficient use of storage by storing only the metadata for holes instead of using real disk blocks, so the physical size of the file will not be changed:

[image]

The [Truncate](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Truncate) function changes the size of the file [using](https://github.com/golang/go//tree/2b50ab2aee75d3c361fcd1eb39e830e2e73056b6/src/os/file_unix.go#L285) the [truncate](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/truncate.2.html) system call. This function changes the size of the file, but, unlike `Seek`, it does not change the I/O offset. The extended part of the file reads as null bytes (‘\0’) and this will change the physical size.

So, answering your question, the correct choice for you will be using the `Truncate` function.

Answer (score 0):

#### [Truncate](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Truncate)

> *func Truncate(name string, size int64) error*
> Truncate changes the size of the named file. If the file is a symbolic link, it changes the size of the link's target. If there is an error, it will be of type *PathError

#### [func (*File) Seek](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Seek)

> *func (f *File) Seek(offset int64, whence int) (ret int64, err error)*
> Seek sets the offset for the next Read or Write on file to offset, interpreted according to whence: 0 means relative to the origin of the file, 1 means relative to the current offset, and 2 means relative to the end. It returns the new offset and an error, if any. The behavior of Seek on a file opened with O_APPEND is not specified.

> If f is a directory, the behavior of Seek varies by operating system; you can seek to the beginning of the directory on Unix-like operating systems, but not on Windows.

So with truncate you change your file size to the the size you set, with seek you **read** the file up to a certain offset.